# Ошибки подклключения к прокси nodejs+request

Tags: node.js, http, proxy, request

Пишу программу для "накрутки" голосов на `rupoll.com` алгоритм таков:

1. Подключаемся по прокси
2. Делаем запрос на голосование
3. Получаем JS код с математическими вычислениями (защита от накрутки)
4. Исполняем код и делаем запрос с результатом вычислений

И так в цикле, но при 99.9% конектов выдает ошибки конекта к прокси вида:

> { [Error: read ECONNRESET] code: 'ECONNRESET', errno: 'ECONNRESET', syscall: 're
>   ad' }

И

> { [Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 98.31.53.20:30684]
>     code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
>     errno: 'ETIMEDOUT',
>     syscall: 'connect',
>     address: '98.31.53.20',
>     port: 30684 }

Код:

```
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio')
var fs = require('fs');

fs.readFile('proxy.txt', function(err, data) {
    var data = data.toString();
    var sp_data = data.split("\r\n");
    for (var i = 0; i < sp_data.length; i++) {
        console.log(i);
        var proxiedRequest = request.defaults({
           'proxy': 'http://'+sp_data[i]
         });
        var options = {
            url: 'http://www.rupoll.com/vote.php',
            method: "POST",
            body: 'poll_id=exbiaofu&vote=7',
            headers: {
                'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:50.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/50.0',
                'Referer': 'http://www.rupoll.com/exbiaofusp.html',
                "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=windows-1251",
            }
        };

        proxiedRequest(options, function(err, resp, body) {
         try {
            console.log(err);
            if (body) {
                var $ = cheerio.load(body);
                //console.log($('script').html());
                var confirm = '';
                var jsod = $('script').html().replace(/\s{2,}/g, ' ').replace("location.replace('", "confirm = '").slice(0, -3) + "';";
                eval(jsod);
                //console.log(confirm);
                proxiedRequest(confirm, function(err, resp, body) {
                    //console.log(body);
                    if (body.indexOf('setTimeout') + 1) {
                        console.log(i+':OK');
                    } else {
                        console.log(i+':ERROR');
                    }
                });
            } else {
                console.log(i+':ERROR');
            }
         } catch (e){}
        });

    }
});
```

В чем может заключатся проблема? Чекеры вроде находят рабочие к примеру 60 из 100 и др..

Что я неверно делаю? Руки не из того места или прокси корявые?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Цикл синхронный, а запросы - асинхронные. Получается, что ты посылаешь всю пачку запросов одновременно, а потом ждёшь на них ответы. Полагаю, что это забивает все соединения. Да и бесплатные прокси оюычно бывают не очень.

**В общем, для начала шли запросы по одному: послал, обработал, послал следующий.**

Другие замечания:

- Не надо игнорировать ошибки в коллбеках.
- `.split("\r\n")` - уверен, что не просто `\n`?
  И укажи кодировку, чтобы сразу получать строку.
- `proxiedRequest` - а не проще ли загнать `proxy` в `options`?
- `eval` - это плохо...
- Там где передаётся `confirm`, не хватает user-agent'а и всего остального.